# How do map a set of points on the surface of a sphere to the surface of a scaled sphere?

Tags: geometry

I have a set of points $P$ on the surface of a sphere of radius $R$.  I wish to change the radius of the sphere to $R_2 = c*R_1$, where $c$ is some positive real number.  Using Cartesian coordinates, how do I map the set of points $P$ to the surface of the new sphere such that the distance between the points remains proportionally the same?

Please assume that we know the point $p_s$ at the center of the sphere.  We can set $p_s = (0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x,y,z) \mapsto (cx,cy,cz)$  (assuming the spheres are both centered at the origin)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know if this was a bias-free way of doing things.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bias", but this mapping will keep distances proportional.